# Hot to make firefox ignore insecure connection errors?

Tags: firefox, certificate

For testing purposes I want to use a local proxy to monitor the network traffic for automated tests. However, with the proxy set in the Network Proxy settings of firefox, I get insecure connection errors like the following:

[image]

How can I disable this check?

I tried to set the value of `security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling` to `false` (as suggested somewhere) without effect.

I strongly prefer an answer in which I change the contents of the `about:config` preferences...